# drupal problem with creating word document files

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i m newbie to drupal presently i m using drupal 6 version

i have to generate the word document files for the selected nodes say (/node/166,node/21)

we dont have any module to generate word documents or to generate pdf files with group of nodes we can generate pdf file for one object

to generate word document file in php 
will be

---

**This is the text for the word file created through php programming
test to create a doc file from php";
    ob_start();
        include('index.php?q=1,2');
        $result = ob_get_clean();
    fwrite($fp, $result);
        echo "executed";
    fclose($fp);
?>**

---

in the above example it generates the word documents,

so i thought  including  'www.example.com/print/166' in the **include** function will do the things 
and i can call to the same function with selected nodes....

later realised that this wont help us because drupal structure is completely different it 
uses only index.php and hooks to serve the requests
and mostly include function needs php fields as inputs

now i am no where to solve my problem 
can any one help me to generate pdf files with bunch of nodes.

please guys
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You must create module with menu. Read here: http://drupal.org/developing/modules

 Also i am recommend to read book: Pro Drupal Development from Vandyk